# Adding more items in the column of a table

Tags: tables

I have the following LaTeX codes as part of my write-up in order to create a table for my simulation results. I am finding it difficult to include the following:  TY=57.48, GH=37.51, XYZ= 5.01 just below the n=50000 all in the first column. Specifically in this order (vertical arrangement):

```
n=50000
TY=57.48
GH=37.51
XYZ= 5.01
```

Thanks!

```
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.3mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=1.8cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{2cm} |c c c c  c c c c}
        \hline
        \hline

        & \emph{True Value}& \emph{Estimate} & \emph{ RMSE } & \emph{Bias  } & \emph{ $\% $Bias  } & \emph{SE   }  &\emph{Coverage} & \emph{ CIL } \\
        \hline
        %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            \multirow{2}{*}{$n=50000$ } & $r_1= 0.033 $&  $\hat{r_1}= 0.03339$ & $0.00161$  &$ 0.000060$  & $0.18146$ & $0.00162$ &  $ 0.954$ & $0.00635$\\     
            & $r_2=0.040$   & $\hat{r_2}=0.04012$  & $ 0.00580$ &$0.000116$ & $ 0.29026$ & $0.00580 $ & $0.952$ & $0.02274$ \\
            \cline{1-9}     

        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\multirow{2}{=}{{$n=50000$ TY=57.48 GH=37.51 XYZ= 5.01}`  with `\arraystretch` =2.4, but please, consider use only `booktabs` rules ....

Comment: @Fran Thanks a lot. It works. I will also consider using booktabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is `\multirow{2}{=}{}` with `\arraystretch =2.4`.

On the other hand, with booktabs rules look better, imho:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.4}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=1.8cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2cm}@{\qquad}c c c c c c c c@{}}\toprule
   & \emph{True Value}& \emph{Estimate} & \emph{ RMSE } & \emph{Bias } & \emph{ $\% $Bias } & \emph{SE } &\emph{Coverage} & \emph{ CIL } \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
\multirow{2}{=}{\parbox{2cm}{$n=50000$ $\text{TY}=57.48$ $\text{GH}=37.51$ $\text{XYZ}= 5.01$}} & $r_1= 0.033 $& $\hat{r_1}= 0.03339$ & $0.00161$ &$ 0.000060$ & $0.18146$ & $0.00162$ & $ 0.954$ & $0.00635$\\ 
 & $r_2=0.040$ & $\hat{r_2}=0.04012$ & $ 0.00580$ &$0.000116$ & $ 0.29026$ & $0.00580 $ & $0.952$ & $0.02274$ \\
 \cline{1-9} 
 \hline 
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```